# gmail bad request

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

I've been getting these off and on for a few months. When I open

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/
```

it gives me

```
Bad Request

Error 400
```

Internet netted some solutions that did not work for me. Anyone know why this is happening and how to get rid of it permanently?  I am using google chrome on Windows.

Comment: This is really off-topic for Server Fault.  It might be on-topic for webapps.stackexchange.com or Super User, but if you've tried the solutions you've found on the internet (no idea what they are since you didn't tell us...) then Google has a [technical support team](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/request.py) who are really the folks who can address your question best.

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to servers , still this problem is very common, its due a problem at your cookies, you need to restart them, checking on google help you can see this link

https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=12911&answer=91343

that talks about your problem.

**Be sure your computer date is correctly set.**

Comment: I've tried most of the stuff on the net. Cleared cookie/session information. Verified time. Tried turning off labs=0 etc. Most of the articles seemed to be from 2008... have they not addressed this issue permanently? When I switch to FireFox, it seems to work well.

Comment: This is super annoying and disappointing.

Comment: try entering to the direct path https://mail.google.com/mail/ca/u/0/?shva=1#inbox, and if not might be cause of your browser, should check on security settings or reinstall it

Comment: I've found out you can get this rolling again by deleting GMAIL_IMP cookie.